# H2 + Jetty + Android issues - java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers can throw a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: android, h2, embedded-jetty

I hope someone can give some insight into this bizarre issue

I have a iJetty WebApp on my android device. We have the ability to clear our H2 DB after the user shuts down their jetty server but the Dalvik vm is online.

I get an exception after the following case:
1. Start server
2. login to system (This creates the H2 db if its not there, and where the connections are made)
3. stop the server (this issues a disconnect to all the connections to the DB)
4. delete the h2 DB from the app (This deletes the h2 db file)
5. start the app
6.  login to system (This creates the H2 db if its not there, and where the connections are made)

Things work fine when I do this twice. But when on the third time i get this exception:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
.
.
.
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:569)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:258)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.<clinit>(BasicDataSource.java:57)
    ... 41 more
```

Notes on the issue:

I looked at http://www.mkyong.com/websphere/basicdatasource-causing-java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-in-websphere/

- We don't init the actual datasource in Spring at all. we do a call in Java: `BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();` whenever a new connection needs to be made.
- When the Jetty server goes down I tried issueing the SQL command "SHUTDOWN" this did not change anything.
- Looking at the code for DriverManager I am confused how the exception could even happen. They do a synchronized on the arraylist they are iterating over.
- I originally posted the issue on the H2 forum to check if they notice it. I don't think its an H2 specific thing. (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/OiKNgnYjOSM)

Any Thoughts would be appreciated

**UPDATE**
Below is the call for Andorid's DriverManager.java for API 17 (It happens in 18 as well). If I can find a link to their repo I will post that

```
    /**
 * Returns an {@code Enumeration} that contains all of the loaded JDBC
 * drivers that the current caller can access.
 *
 * @return An {@code Enumeration} containing all the currently loaded JDBC
 *         {@code Drivers}.
 */
public static Enumeration<Driver> getDrivers() {
    /*
     * Synchronize to avoid clashes with additions and removals of drivers
     * in the DriverSet
     */
    ClassLoader callerClassLoader = VMStack.getCallingClassLoader();
    synchronized (theDrivers) {
        ArrayList<Driver> result = new ArrayList<Driver>();
        for (Driver driver : theDrivers) { // THIS IS THE OFFENDING LINE
            if (DriverManager.isClassFromClassLoader(driver, callerClassLoader)) {
                result.add(driver);
            }
        }
        return Collections.enumeration(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post DriverManager code.

Comment: @Tarik He mentioned running on Android, the [java.sql.DriverManager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik.git/+/89c1feb0a69a7707b271086e749975b3f7acacf7/libcore/sql/src/main/java/java/sql/DriverManager.java) code is available, however the line numbers don't match up, which is suspect, as that code has had only 2 revisions, initial commit + CupCake update.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I jsut saw your post. I added the method thats causing the issue and I saw your link. Which API level is that in reference to?

Comment: Went through DriverManager code you provided and it is puzzling indeed.

Comment: @Tarik The prior link is old, looks like they moved libcore to its own repo, here's the [Android 4.3 r3.1 version of java.sql.DriverManager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-4.3_r3.1/luni/src/main/java/java/sql/DriverManager.java)

Comment: Yup, line 262 is what is offending on link @Tarik provided. I had to other devs look at the DriverManager code and I do not get how the exception can happen if they are sychronizing on the list of drivers